# class access control: What if there is readonly access controller?

Tags: class, oop

While I was using class, I found that some attributes, especially the ones which are boolean, are often read by other instances. For example,

```
class Node{
private:
    int item;
    bool visited;
public:
    bool isVisited(){return visited;}
    void bar(){
        ...
        visited=true;
        ...
    }
};

class Graph{
private:
    vector<Node> nodes;
public:
    void bar(int idx){
        if(nodes[idx].isVidited()){
            ...
            nodes[idx].foo();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In that case if visited is only changed by the methods of the class Node, then the access controller of the attribute visited shouldn't always be private in perspective of reading. What if there is an access controller 'readonly' that is opened to reading, closed to writing? I think that is useful when defining state attributes. Will there be any side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some languages, there is getter/setter which works as an api of a private value.
It seems like a public value, but internally the methods control the private member variable, not the code with '=' operator itself.

```
//TYPESCRIPT
class Foo{
    private _name:string
    constructor(n:string){this._name=n}

    get name(){return this._name}
    //set name(n:string){this._name=n}
}

const foo=new Foo('Jack jack')
console.log(foo.name)  //[LOG]: "Jack jack"

foo.name='hudson'  //[ERR]: Cannot set property name of #<Foo> which has only a getter
```

The code above shows how a readonly property is set. There is only a getter which delivers exactly the same value of the private member variable '_name', but since setter is not defined, only the class itself can change the value and  is not able to edit from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried marking the Graph class as `friend` inside the Node class?

This facilitates accessing the private members of the Node class by the Graph class.

Comment: Making Graph friend of Node means Graph can BOTH read/write. I think the desirable access is that Node can only be read, not be written.

Comment: And declaring only a getter method? If you return the value 'as-is', there is no possibility to modify it and you can get a copy of the value.